# Neural network to figure out the meaning of user input

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to make a neural network try to figure out the meaning of input(keyboard keys in this case) according to the user.

I have multiple possible output "commands" that the NN can interpret the inputs to mean, and at each state certain outputs can count as beneficial while others are a detriment

When the NN starts up for the first time, no input should have any particular meaning to it but as time goes on I want the NN to be able to figure out what the user most likely meant.

I've tried a Multilayer perceptron NN that has as many input nodes as there are physical inputs and as many output nodes as there are commands and a number of nodes equal to the sum of the other two layers as a single hidden layer, in this case it is then a 5,15,10.

The NN assumes that the user will only make moves that are in the NN's best interest.

So far it seems the NN is just figuring out what is the command it can take that will most likely result in a beneficial move, regardless of the input key rather than trying to figure out what key should result in what move according to the user.

Because of this I'm wondering (most likely wrong) if I should produce a separate NN for each input to try and figure out the current output according to the user.

Is there a different type of NN I should look into that will work better, and is there a recommended configuration for this problem?
I'll be happy with some recommendations of reading material that would help in this particular problem.

I'm at best an amateur in NN and would like to learn a lot more about the whole field, But I'm trying to focus my efforts on this problem for now.

Comment: tell me one, what kind of actions do you need, to guess key as key? Or Key as representation of symbol? To guess words?

Comment: Well to put it in context: It's in kind of a game environment, and the NN is responsible for a mouse in a maze, the player presses buttons to give input, and the NN is suppose to interpret this as a command to allow the mouse navigate a maze filled with hazards. examples of commands are like Go North or East, Jump. continue, reverse. The idea  a bit abstract and a bit of an experiment. But it is to have the user create a input interface with the mouse to help it navigate when all of the inputs have no concrete meaning. Having more possible commands than there are inputs is also intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Accordng to me you want the output to be according to behaviour of the player as number of inputs are more than in actual case. So according to me there should be some type of memory for the actions taken by the player in order to find the patterns.This can be done using **Long Short term Memory**.